# Eclipse CDT and GDB debugging. Value of struct members

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I just switched from Visual Studio 2010 to Eclipse (Ubuntu).

I have a global initialized structure like this CvCapture *capture.

How can I get values of capture members in debug window? capture even is not shown in Variables window. I have added watch expression, but I don't get members values of capture.

**Edited:** Screenshot http://tinypic.com/r/10s6x3q/5 . Plus I can't Add Global Variable in Variables window. It's inactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct CvCapture*` is an opaque handle (see [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)) : *users are not supposed to see what is inside*.
Its content is declared only in the library code, you cannot find it in any exported include like highgui.h (where it is only forward-declared), and neither does Eclipse.

**What you can do :**
Recompile the highgui library in debug-mode, link your program with it, launch a debugging session and enter one of the library's functions such as `cvGetCaptureProperty()`. Once there gdb will be able to see the content of `struct CvCapture` (defined in _highgui.h) and Eclipse will show it to you.